# Remove title attribute from tag cloud widget

Tags: taxonomy, title, cloud

I use the built-in tag cloud widget and it's outputting the terms with a title attribute on hover that says "x Topics". How can I remove this title attribute, or better yet, change it to something more meaningful for the current terms.

I have already tried this code, but it does not appear to be working:

```
// remove the title attribute from tag cloud widget
add_filter('wp_widget_tag_cloud', 'remove_tag_title_attributes');
function remove_tag_title_attributes($output) {
    $output = preg_replace('title="(.+)"', '', $output);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this plugin is what you're looking for?
http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-tag-cloud-widget/other_notes/ Looks like you can edit the title and then some.

Comment: @mtuttle I've seen that plugin before but didn't want all the functionality. However, since there appeared to not be a native hook for changing the title, I've just used it for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you think that code would work? There is no hook named `wp_widget_tag_cloud` that I can find, and there is [no hook specifically meant for altering that attribute](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/category-template.php#L674). But you can pass a `topic_count_text_callback` to [`wp_tag_cloud`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud), which is what [generates the tag cloud for the widget](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L1058), and there is a hook that allows you to alter the widget's tag cloud arguments.

```
function tag_count_cb($count) {
  return 'test';
}

function remove_tag_title_attributes($args) {
  $args['topic_count_text_callback'] = 'tag_count_cb';
    var_dump($args);
  return $args;
}
add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args', 'remove_tag_title_attributes');
```

But you don't have much to work with-- just the tag count. To get more to work with you will need to do something more like what you trying but with a different regex and a different hook.

```
function tag_cloud_attribute_rebuild($match) {
  $a = "<a href='%s' class='%s' title='%s' style='%s'>%s</a>";
  return sprintf(
    $a,
    $match[1],
    $match[2],
    $match[3],
    $match[4],
    $match[5]
  );
}

function remove_tag_title_attributes($output) {
  $pattern = "|<a href='([^']*?)' class='([^']*?)' title='([^']*?)' style='([^']*?)'>([^<]*)</a>|";
  $output = preg_replace_callback($pattern,'tag_cloud_attribute_rebuild',$output);
  return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_tag_cloud', 'remove_tag_title_attributes');
```

The title is `$match[3]`. The other information is to give you some information to work with. Alter `$match[3]` before the `sprintf`. If that isn't enough information you will have to extract the `ID` from `$match[2]` or use the tag name in `$match[5]` and run a query, but that will be *very* labor intensive for the server.

That is how you would do it with the Core widget. Another option would be to rebuild the widget under a different name-- that is, make your own widget using the Core widget as a model--and include altered versions of whatever functions you need.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer. I also checked the answer that @toscho linked to and this simple thing doesn't seem to be that simple. I'll just use a plugin until there is a native hook for altering the title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function wp_tag_cloud_remove_title_attributes($return) {
        // This function uses single quotes
        $return = preg_replace("` title='(.+)'`", "", $return);
    return $return;
}
add_filter('wp_tag_cloud', 'wp_tag_cloud_remove_title_attributes');
```

Comment: This does remove the title, but for some reason it breaks the smaller/bigger terms output. Thanks anyway, I went with a plugin eventually.

Comment: NEVER use reserved word as variable. Using return as variable is bad practice